# Javascript replace w Regex adding quote at end

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm doing a javascript replace with a regex function, and when I return the code, there is always an extra double quote " at the end of the return URL. If I alert() the URL the quote does not show, only when I return the link in the function.

```
<div class="postbody">
<a href="http://www.mystore.com/product/upc0009384775" class="postlink">Faux Leather Deluxe Heated Seat Cushion</a>
</div>
<script>
 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('postbody');
for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
{
    elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(/\"((?:http:\/\/|http:\/\/www.)mystore.)([a-zA-Z.]{2,5}\/)(product\/)([A-Za-z0-9]*)/gi,
        function(match,match2,match3,match4,match5)
        {
            return match2+'co.uk'+'/'+match4+match5+'/?referral=us-store&';
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

The resulting HTML is:

```
<div class="postbody">
<a class="postlink" href="http://www.mystore.co.uk/product/upc0009384775/?referral=us-store&amp;&quot;">Faux Leather Deluxe Heated Seat Cushion</a>
</div>
```

I've tried lots of things, but can't seem to figure it out even after super-simplifying the code to what you see here.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Update, better description:** The reason that the " is included is because of how the DOM works. You are not using the first match, so the quote is being excluded from the returned string, but you are still replacing the quote. The DOM will automatically correct the HTML, and add the quotes around the returned URL (which just has a single quote).

The following examples should display how this works in steps: http://jsfiddle.net/danschultzer/HAG9j/3/

To fix the second issue you experience of not handling URL's with query parameters, just change the regex to be more open (added in the example above):

```
/\"((?:http:\/\/|http:\/\/www.)mystore.)([a-zA-Z.]{2,5}\/)(product\/)(.*)\"/gi
```

Do note that you need to parse the query values right in the replace method. You should be able to replace the `/?` with '?&'.

---

It is because your regex doesn't match the ending quote. You start correctly by matching the first quote, but the second one you don't match.

Change the regex to

```
/\"((?:http:\/\/|http:\/\/www.)mystore.)([a-zA-Z.]{2,5}\/)(product\/)([A-Za-z0-9]*)\"/gi
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danschultzer/HAG9j/

But I recommend that you make the regex even more specific and target the href= also. Of course it depends what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: But I'm not replacing/adding an ending quote to the text I'm replacing, so why is it adding one? Also, some links have more text and variables after the 'upc0009384775' so then the regex doesn't work if I match the ending quote. http://jsfiddle.net/UQ3u9/

Comment: It is not _adding_ one – _you_ are leaving the one that’s already there in place.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure exactly what was going on. It appears that for some reason, with the replace function, the browser was appending " to the returned value.

After staring at it some more, I realized my regex was searching for an opening double quote, but I wasn't returning the opening double quote. Once I added the opening double quote to the return, the browser (or Javascript I'm not sure) was no longer appending " to the returned string.

```
<div class="postbody">
<a href="http://www.mystore.com/product/upc0009384775" class="postlink">Faux Leather Deluxe Heated Seat Cushion</a>
</div>
<script>
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('postbody');
for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
{
    elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(/\"((?:http:\/\/|http:\/\/www.)mystore.)([a-zA-Z.]{2,5}\/)(product\/)([A-Za-z0-9]*)/gi,
    function(match,match2,match3,match4,match5)
    {
        return '"'+match2+'co.uk'+'/'+match4+match5+'/?referral=us-store&';
    }
);
```

}